# error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' and NO both On windows 10. How to do root login?

Tags: mysql, windows, localhost, root

X:\A\Y\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin>**mysql --version**

mysql  Ver 14.14 **Distrib 5.5.60, for Win64** (AMD64)

So Using windows 10 and mysql 5.5 version. Not with phpmyadmin or WAMP.

> mysql -u root

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

> mysql -u root -p

error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

> mysql

It does not provide root access or no rights to update mysql database access.
So no insert /update /alter SQL command will work.

There is not any configuration.ini under /bin. and some ini files are outside /bin/../ but which to change.

I am accessing local mysql server on my system.

Comment: Check your MySQL boot log to see what default password was assigned. Newer versions set one that's random.

Comment: Windows installation asked root password, I remember password very well.